# Insert images in a tab activity using fragments

Tags: android

I saw that TabActivity is deprecated so I'm trying to obtain the same in a fragment activity.
Previousely I had created layout like this for each tab:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_selected" android:state_selected="true"    android:state_pressed="false" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_unselected" android:state_selected="false" />
 </selector>
```

How to use them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...I was just missing to call getDrawable in setIndicator..